# Average of number in SQL

Tags: sql, math, average

This might be very simple, but I can't understand why the final result is 500.

What is the mathematical operation done to get to that result?

[Table_query_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkiOs.png)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The query select two rows: one with 450 and the other with 550. The average value is 500.

Comment: Only SPEAKER and KEYBOARD satisfied your where clause and their prices are 550 and 450. (550 + 450) / 2 = 1000 / 2 = 500 which is correct. There's no problem with your answer.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your table data and query as text here instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your table there are two rows with pro_com = 16. Their values are 450 and 550, the average of which is 500.

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked the second record pro_com 16

Answer (score 0):

AVG () computes the average of a set of values by dividing the sum of those values by the count of nonnull values. If the sum exceeds the maximum value for the data type of the return value, AVG() will return an error.